# Excluding a device from android app download based on RAM requirements?

Tags: android, google-play, ram

Can I exclude a device from downloading my app from the android market by determining how much RAM the device has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select individually the devices that don't have enough RAM and block them in the market.

You can't do it automatically, but you can do it by hand. You have that option after you submit your app to the market.

In any case you really should consider if you should have that requirement or improve the performance of your app. I think you should choose the second option :)

Comment: Choose the second option: always.